# How do I show a record on a Webform within Dynamics 365's Configuration Page?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a HTML webpage in Microsoft Dynamics 365 that I'm using as a Configuration Page. It allows the user to enter their information (Name, Address, City, State, Zip/Postal, and their Billing Information such as Card Name, Card Number, expiration date, etc). I use the CRM Rest Builder's WebAPI to synchronously create the record in the database once the user enters all their information and clicks the Submit button.

What I am wondering about is whenever the user clicks the D365 Solution and loads the configuration page, it needs to show all the inputted data dynamically, so the user doesn't have to re-enter inputted data on the form (i.e. each time they click the configuration page showing the HTML file, it is not blank, their data exists). However, I am configuring it in such a way that the user makes changes only to the form.

What I've tried is using CRM Rest Builder to generate JavaScript to retrieve a single record by the record's ID (32-hexadecimal). But when I add the method of retrieving into the body of the form, using the onLoad function, the user's data doesn't load for some reason. I have included the GUID of the record for reference.

Please see the code:

```js
function retrieveRecord() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/new_subscriptions(67EBDC8C-CFA5-E811-A963-000D3A3ACAF8)?$select=new_name,new_state,new_zippostal, new_cardname", false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var new_name = result["new_name"];
                var new_state = result["new_state"];
                var new_zippostal = result["new_zippostal"];
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
      }
```

```html
<body onload="retrieveRecord()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
     Status: <input type="text" name="Name" id="new_status">
      <h2>Address Information:</h2>
      Name: <input type="text" name="Name" id="new_name"><br>
      State: <select id="new_state">
                     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                     <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                     <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                     <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                     <option value="CA">California</option>
                     <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                     <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                     <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                     <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                     <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                     <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                     <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                     <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                     <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                     <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                     <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                     <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                     <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                     <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                     <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                     <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                     <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                     <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                     <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                     <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                     <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                     <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                     <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                     <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                     <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                     <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                     <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                     <option value="NY">New York</option>
                     <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                     <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                     <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                     <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                     <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                     <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                     <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                     <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                     <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                     <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                     <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                     <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                     <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                     <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                     <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                     <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                     <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                     <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select><br>
      Zip/Postal: <input type="text" name="Zip/Postal" id="new_zippostal"><br>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```